# Using SfDateRangePicker, how can I set numberOfWeeksInView depending on the month?

Tags: flutter, calendar, syncfusion

Changing the numberOfWeeksInView from 6 to 5 removes the first week instead of last week. I couldn't find an option on https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar

I changed the numberOfWeeksInView on onViewChanged to determine the month if I have to add or remove excess weeks but it doesn't eliminate the issue.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: I didn't know that, Thank you!

Comment: Common response, which is why I have that paragraph on a hotkey, and get to use it at least 2-3 times per week. :)